# Need help in drag and drop uploading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

When I select and drag and drop multiple files in the drop files area, it goes to Uploads folder but I see only one item under the drop files area each time when uploading.
I want to show multiple files instead of one file/item under the drop files area when uploading.
How can I do that?

`if(file_exists($serverpath))` is not working. I don't know why.
Can you people look into it?
I want the same uploaded file rename from 0 to 1,2,3 when I upload `files` when files exist(`if(file_exists($serverpath))`) in `Uploads` folder.

When I click on a image it shows a image box. 
I need the `.Crop-Box` resizable and draggable.
I am using mozilla firefox and google chrome.

Here is the code:

```css
*{margin:0; padding:0;}

body{background:black;}

#Container{
           margin:200px auto;
     width:620px;
     padding-bottom:20px;
     background:#ffffff;
     color:black;
     border:1px solid gray;
     border-radius:5px;
    }
    
#Text{
      margin:20px;
   color:green;
   font-family:verdana;
   font-size:12pt;
  }
  
#Drop{
      margin:20px auto;
   padding:20px;
   color:gray;
   width:500px;
   height:40px;
   background:#f1f1f1;
   border:1px dotted #ccc;
   border-radius:5px;
  }
  
.progressbar{
             margin:20px auto;
    width:80%;
    height:20px;
    background:#ddd;
    border-radius:5px;
    display:none;
   }
   
.progress{
          width:0%;
    height:20px;
    border-radius:5px;
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, lightblue, #2196f3);
   }
   
.progresstext{
              float:right;
    }

.InsertInto{
            margin-top:20px;
     }
    
.image{
       margin:20px;
    width:15%;
    height:20%;
    display:none;
   }

.FileDiv{
         margin-bottom:20px;
  }
   
.filenam{
   position:absolute;
   margin-top:-57px;
   margin-left:140px;
     }
    
#RealFile{
          margin:20px;
       display:none;
      }
  
#UploadImage{
             margin-left:100px;
    padding:20px 200px;
    background:#2196f3;
    color:white;
    border:none;
    border-radius:5px;
    cursor:pointer;
   }

button:focus{
           outline:none;
    }
   
#Submit{
  margin-left:100px;
  padding:20px 200px;
     background:#219549;
     color:white;
  border:none;
  border-radius:5px;
  cursor:pointer;
    }
    
.Crop-Main{
     position:relative;
     width:600px;
     min-width:600px;
     height:520px;
     margin:100px auto;
     padding:20px;
     background:#f1f1f1;
     color:black;
     border:1px solid #ccc;
     border-radius:5px;
     z-index:1;
     display:none;
    }

#Close{
       background:#2196f3;
    color:white;
    padding:10px;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-size:12pt;
    cursor:pointer;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin:20px;
    margin-right:0px;
    float:right;
    user-select:none;
   }
    
.Crop-Container{
                position:relative;
    width:600px;
    margin:80px auto;
    min-height:300px;
      }

.Crop-Container img{
                   width:600px;
       user-select:none;
      }
      
.Crop-Box{
          position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:rgba(69,69,69,0.6);
    border:1px solid white;
    z-index:2;
    cursor:move;
   }
   
#Save{
      position:absolute;
   padding:20px 80px;
   background:green;
   color:white;
   border:none;
   border-radius:5px;
   font-family:verdana;
   font-size:12pt;
   cursor:pointer;
   margin:-70px 200px;
  }
  
.InsertInto img{
               cursor:pointer;
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>

<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>



<div class="Crop-Main">

<span id="Close">X</span>

<div class="Crop-Container">

<img src=""/>

<div class="Crop-Box"></div>

</div>

<button id="Save" onclick="save()">Save</button>

</div>




<div id="Container">

<div id="Text">Advanced File Uploader</div>

<div id="Drop">Drop files here</div>

<div class="progressbar">

<div class="progress"></div>

<div class="progresstext">0%</div>

</div>



<div class="InsertInto">

</div>


<input type="file" name="realfile" id="RealFile" multiple="true"><br/><br/>

<button id="UploadImage" type="button">Upload</button>

<br/><br/>


<form action="uploads.php" method="POST" id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">



<input type="submit" name="submit" id="Submit" value="Submit">

</form>

</div>

<script>
var obj = document.querySelector("#Drop");

var realf = document.querySelector("#RealFile");

obj.ondragover = function(e){

$(this).css("border-color","green");

return false; 

}

obj.ondragleave = function(e){

return false;

$(this).css("border","none"); 

}

obj.ondrop = function(e){

e.preventDefault();

$(this).css("border-color","#2196f3"); 

var files = e.dataTransfer.files;

upload(files);

console.log(files);

}



realf.onchange = function(e){

var files = e.currentTarget.files;

upload(files);

console.log(files);

}



function upload(e){

var formdata = new FormData();

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

var i;

for(i=0; i < e.length; i++){

formdata.append("realfile[]", e[i]);

}

if(xhttp.upload){

xhttp.open("POST", "upload.php", true);

xhttp.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e){

var parcent = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;

document.querySelector(".progressbar").style.display = "block";

document.querySelector(".progress").style.width = parcent+"%";

document.querySelector(".progresstext").innerHTML = parcent+"%";

});

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){

if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200){

var result;

result = this.responseText;

var newresult = JSON.parse(result);

var i;

document.querySelector(".progressbar").style.display = "none";

var insertinto = document.querySelector(".InsertInto");

var filediv = document.createElement("DIV");

filediv.className = "FileDiv";

insertinto.appendChild(filediv);

var img = document.createElement("IMG");

img.className = "image";

filediv.appendChild(img);

img.setAttribute("src",newresult.url);

img.setAttribute("width","100%");

img.setAttribute("height","100%");

img.style.display = "block";

img.addEventListener("click", function(e){

var cropmain = document.querySelector(".Crop-Main");

cropmain.style.display = "block";

document.querySelector("#Container").style.display = "none";

var imgsrc = $(this).attr("src");

$(".Crop-Container img").attr("src", imgsrc);

});

var close = document.querySelector("#Close");

close.addEventListener("click", function(e){

document.querySelector(".Crop-Main").style.display = "none";

document.querySelector("#Container").style.display = "block";

});


var filenam = document.createElement("DIV");

filenam.className = "filenam";

filenam.innerHTML = newresult.name;

insertinto.appendChild(filenam);

if(newresult != "" && newresult != "Not Ok"){

for(i=0; i<newresult.length; i++){

if(newresult[i].status == true){



}

}

}








console.log(xhttp.responseText);

}

}

xhttp.send(formdata);

}

}

$("#UploadImage").click(function(e){

$("#RealFile").click();

});

$(".InsertInto").on("click", ".InsertInto img", function(){

var img = $(this).attr("src");

$(".Crop-Container").find("img").attr("src", img);

var w = $(".Crop-Container img").width();

var h = $(".Crop-Container img").height();

$(".Crop-Container").width(w);

$(".Crop-Container").height(h);



document.querySelector(".Container").style.display = "none";

document.querySelector(".Crop-Main").style.display = "block";

});


</script>

</body>

</html>
```

PHP

```html
<?php

$status = array();

$allow = array("image/jpeg", "image/png");


 
 //print "<pre>"
 //print_r($_FILES["file"]);
 //print "</pre>"
 
 foreach($_FILES["realfile"]["name"] as $pos => $val){
  
  if(!in_array(strtolower($_FILES["realfile"]["type"][$pos]), $allow)){
   
   $status = array(
       
          "name" => $_FILES["realfile"]["name"],       
          "type" => $_FILES["realfile"]["type"],
          "url" => "",
          "message" => "Invalid file type",
          "status" => false
       
        );
   
  }
  else{
   
   $tmpname = $_FILES['realfile']['tmp_name'][$pos];
   
   $filename = $_FILES["realfile"]["name"][$pos];
   
   //$path = "Uploads/".$filename;
   
   $addition = 0;
   
   $serverpath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."Uploads/".$filename;
   
   if(file_exists($serverpath)){
    
    while(file_exists($serverpath)){
     
     $addition = $addition + 1;
     
     $info = pathinfo($serverpath);
     
     $directory = $info["dirname"];
         
     $oldname = $info["filename"];

     $oldext = $info["extension"];
     
     $serverpath = $directory."/".$oldname.$addition.".".$oldext;
 
    }
    
    $serverpath = "Uploads/".$oldname.$addition.".".$oldext;
    
    
    
   }
   else{
    
    $serverpath = "Uploads/".$filename;
    
   }
   
   move_uploaded_file($tmpname, $serverpath);
    
    $status = array(
       
              "name" => $_FILES["realfile"]["name"][$pos],       
              "type" => $_FILES["realfile"]["type"][$pos],
              "url" => $serverpath,
              "message" => "File Uploaded",
              "status" => true
       
            );
    
  }
 
      
 
 }

 
echo json_encode($status); 
?>
```